# the wrong height of linearlayout after oncreate() method, why?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to get height of the linearlayout by the getHeight(), but I find the height was wrong, so I do something to check mistake :
 first: int height=linearLayout.getheight() after oncreate() method.

and then linearLayout.setpadding(0,-height,0,0),

but result is the linearLayout content Not completely hidden.
 why?

the plan_detail_course_layout_summary.xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#f4f4f4"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="课程简介"
    android:textColor="#034187"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_detail_intro_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#929496"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/course_detail_intro_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="更多"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/course_intro_border" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the core code :

```
LinearLayout layout_course_summary = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.plan_detail_course_layout_summary);

int height=layout_course_summary.getHeight();
    layout_course_summary.setPadding(0, -height, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout has not completed by the end of onCreate. You can register a layout listener to be notified when layout is completed and the (correct) height is available. For example:

```
layout_course_summary.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int height = layout_course_summary.getHeight();

        ...

        layout_course_summary.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14): android.view.ViewTreeObserver#removeOnGlobalLayoutListener,but i want Compatible to the api 14

Comment: I believe [removeOnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)) in API 16 replaced [removeGlobalOnLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)). removeGlobalOnLayoutListener should still work in API 14.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct approach :

```
LinearLayout layout_course_summary = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.plan_detail_course_layout_summary);

ViewTreeObserver observer= layout_course_summary.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                               int height=layout_course_summary.getHeight();
                                               layout_course_summary.setPadding(0, -height, 0, 0);
                    }
                });
```